# How do I search for previous non-empty cell in column in Excel?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I would greatly appreciate help in finding an Excel formula that would search for the *previous* (not *last*) non-empty cell in the column, and then add 1. The empty cells are not consistently separated apart.

```
ColA
1 
2

3

4
5
6


7
8
```

I prefer a formula, but I'm open to VBA. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's the output supposed to be? What's the data you're starting with? Which of the numbers above is the formula supposed to produce? As a guess, in `A2`, `=MAX($A$1:A1)+1` and then copy to other cells to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming values in column A can be sorted OR unsorted.

[image: Previous]

Colum previous + 1 = previous non-empty cell value + 1

```
=IF(ROW(B3)=MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$14)),B3,OFFSET($B$2,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B$3)=TRUE,0,ROW(B2:B$3)))-ROW($B$2),0)+1)
```

Notes :

For the first lines (no previous cell), the default value of the cell is set.
All "previous+1" values are calculated even for blank cells (modifiable).

[Sheet](https://covid19.framadrop.org/lufi/r/XzxuCSs54X#iQNRWYvFJC7P3K4epuzjKPlAmrU0eDR53Co0vIRAUw4=)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to consider this formula, entered in Cell A3 and copied down from there.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(A$1:A2)),A$1:A2)+1
```

The advantage of this formula is also its disadvantage: It allows a mixture of numbers and text above it, will find the last number and add 1 to it. However, if there is no number it will throw an error which is easy to trap with IFERROR() but that makes the formula too unwieldy. So I recommend to enter it in row 3 and enter a starting number in A2.

@BigBen's recommendation of the MAX() function is what I have previously used when faced with similar requirements but LOOKUP() may be able to perform better under some circumstances.